# Magento 2 : Run command line without prompt confirmation

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, cli, command-line, command

When I run:

```
bin/magento setup:config:set --http-cache-hosts=172.xx.xx.xx
```

I get a command prompt:

```
Overwrite the existing configuration for http-cache-hosts?[Y/n]
```

I want to use this into a bash script so I do not want user interaction.

I can do it by using a hackish way, but I do not like it:

```
yes Y | script.sh
```

Is there a way to force this to use the default value Y?

Comment: Please do remember to accept the answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use -n parameter to disable interactive mode and assume yes.

```
 -n, --no-interaction                                                                     Do not ask any interactive question
```

So, your final command will be

```
bin/magento setup:config:set --http-cache-hosts=172.xx.xx.xx -n
```

Answer (score 0):

[Magento documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands.html) shows that appending -n or --no-interaction to your command should result in no interactive questions. However, in my real-world use of Magento 2.3.0 this has proven to not be the case. If I leave off the -n or --no-interaction parameters then my command is successful, though it does prompt with [Y/n]. If I include the -n or --no-interaction parameters then the command appears to succeed with no prompts. Unfortunately in reality none of the parameters end up succeeding. I don't currently have a workaround.